# 2d array table form print out

Tags: sorting, multidimensional-array

---

so if a user input 9 random numbers

my code prints like this in its sorted form

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

but I want it to print like a table form

like this

```
1   2   3

4   5   6

7   8   9
```

The output after running the code appears as follows:

```
Please enter number of rows: 3
Please enter number of columns: 3
Please enter 9 numbers to sort: 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
Sorted numbers:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
<emtpy line>
```

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class table 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
```

```
        System.out.println("Sorted numbers: ");
        for(int x = 0; x < matrix.length; x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < matrix[x].length; y++)      
            {
                System.out.print(matrix[x][y] + " ");
            }
    
        System.out.println(" ");
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Please copy and paste output rather than submitting images of output in the future

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is here:

```
for(int x = 0; x < matrix.length; x++)
    for (int y = 0; y < matrix[x].length; y++)      
    {
        System.out.print(matrix[x][y] + " ");
    }

System.out.println(" ");
```

You didn't enclose your print statement in the outer for loop. If you add brackets, everything in your for loop will execute.

```
for(int x = 0; x < matrix.length; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < matrix[x].length; y++)      
    {
        System.out.print(matrix[x][y] + " ");
    }

    System.out.println(" ");
}
```

This way your inner for loop will execute printing all your numbers on a line followed by the println execution and then it repeats.

With this modification, I have arrived at this output:

```
Please enter number of rows: 3
Please enter number of columns: 3
Please enter 9 numbers to sort: 8 7 6 4 3 1 2 5 9
Sorted numbers: 
1 2 3  
4 5 6  
7 8 9  
<empty line>
```